# Bash script to configure network interfaces

Tags: linux, bash, unix, network-programming, network-interface

I'm a network and OS student, and I have to make a script that does the following:

It can be called with or without parameters. If called with parameters, it must recieve the name of a network interface (e.g: eth0) and a "name of a configuration profile".

Well, I am very lost, since I have no idea about what a "network interface configuration profile" is. I don't know what I am being asked for. I don't know how to "create a profile for a network configuration" from a bash script, and I don't know how to create those "files" or whatsoever and "put content in them".

Also, I need to setup the following for a selected network interface:

-IP
-Netmask (these two can be done with ifconfig, right?)
-Gateway
-Proxy

I think I know how to configure the first two, but how do I configure the gateway and proxy of a network interface given its name?

Any advice will be extremely appreciated. This is my last task before finishing my course, and I depend on this to move forward.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That kind of looks like your homework :)

Comment: Since you seem to know so little of what is expected, wouldn't asking your tutor for help/clarification be a better idea?

Comment: It IS my homework. I'm not asking for you guys to do it for me, I'm aware of that. I'm just asking for some general advices. I'm only in 1st year, so I really don't know of this stuff yet. And my teacher won't give so many hints either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0

route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0

export http_proxy='http://ip:port/'